# Flutter web release build freezes in Flutter 3.13

Tags: flutter, freeze

I have the issue that my app freezes but only with release builds. With freezes I mean that it's not responding and all animations are frozen, and even the refresh button of the browser is not responsive. Both in Edge and Chrome. And it only happens in Flutter 3.13, not in 3.10. My app is for web and desktop (windows) and the desktop version works fine. It also happens in profile builds but not in debug builds, which makes it very hard to debug. While this happens my Task Manager shows a persistent CPU usage of 15% for the Chrome process. The memory stays the same.

The project code is very big and complex so it's not possible to show code to reproduce, but I'll try to explain what happens. What I have is a login page which leads to a loading page which leads to a main page. It freezes already while displaying the loading page but through  debugging using print statements I could see that the main page code was actually already reached. When I leave out sections of the widget tree in the main page code it comes a bit further but still eventually freezes. The strange thing is though that when I directly navigate to the main page skipping the login and loading screen it seems to work fine. As if the navigating itself might cause problems. I'm using the latest version of GetX (4.6.6) for routing and I thought the problem might be there but I tried removing all GetX related routing code and remaking it with Flutter's normal navigating system but the problem still exists.

Any idea what could be the problem or how I could debug this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. The problem was the package [flutter_widget_from_html_core](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widget_from_html_core). I was using version 0.9.1. This error was described here on its github: https://github.com/daohoangson/flutter_widget_from_html/issues/1007

Using the latest version of this package (0.10.5) solved the issue.

So a lesson for myself is to try to first update all packages. Although it's still frustrating that there was no indication that this package was the culprit. And my project has a long list of dependencies so it can be quite cumbersome to check them all